# Anything related to Zurb Foundation in Node JS throws the same error

Tags: npm, sass, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to access the template from this repository: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template
I successfully cloned the repository, but apparently, in order to get the actual sass, I need to install npm dependencies. So I ran npm install, only to get this error:

```
events.js:160░░░░░░⸩ ⠼ extract:interpret: sill extract interpret@1.0.4
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:193:12)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:240:5)
    at PassThrough.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:477:10)
    at ReadEntry.entry.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/extract-stream.js:19:41)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at ReadEntry.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at ReadEntry.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:296:25)
    at ReadEntry.[maybeEmitEnd] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:249:12)
    at ReadEntry.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:162:27)
    at Unpack.[consumeBody] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:210:13)
    at Unpack.[consumeChunkSub] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:391:40)
    at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:362:30)
    at Unzip.(anonymous function).on.chunk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:291:59)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Unzip.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Unzip.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:296:25)
```

I am using npm version 6.0.0 and node v6.11.2. Running on a mac.

After this I tried installing the foundation cli with `npm install foundation-cli --global`, but got the exact same error. As far as I know, I meet all the requirements as listed on the [github repository](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template), not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: An alternative solution could be to just tell me where the bare sass for foundation is, I've been looking all over and there doesn't seem to be a very easy way to get it. (At least not one that hasn't given me errors like this one)

Comment: Are you cloning the right project, https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites ?

Comment: If you look at the short instructions on the github page I referenced, I just copy and pasted the clone command they had listed, which is, `git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template projectname`

Comment: Also, I really just want the template, which is supposed to just come with the sass and a compiler, not anything else

Comment: I just tried running npm install on github.com/zurb/foundation-sites. Same exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out it was either my npm or node version. I updated both to the most recent (npm 6.4.1, node v10.8.0) versions, and `npm install` ran fine. I suppose what can be learned here is that when dealing with zurb foundation, just try to use the latest software.